# Visual Foxpro 9 - Tapix sample

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro, tapi

suddenly charged with trying to out why a form which uses TAPIEx is no longer working I find my self lacking in using the Tapi OLEControl

Can anyone offer sample VFP code to help me gain an insight into how the control works
my foxpro is pretty extensive but Tapi .....

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion and examples around faxing with TAPI [her](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~TapiFaxAutomation~WIN_COM_API)e on the Visual Foxpro Wiki.

Comment: If that doesn't help, often examples in VBScript or Visual Basic 6 can be readily translated to VFP.